# Encryption and decryption binary files with c#

Tags: c#, encryption, binaryfiles

There are lot of examples of encrypting/decrypting passwords and simple text files with c#, available on web. But I havn't found any example on encrypting or decrypting entire binary file like .exe or .mdb file.

Can anybody provide an example on encrypting/decrypting binary file or can provide some links.

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Comment: encryption usually works on bytes, so surely any sample that works on bytes should work on a file?

Comment: agree with Marc. If you notice carefully, all samples working with text would be converting string/characters into byte stream using some kind of encoding (base64, utf8 etc). While decrypting, it would be doing reverse i.e. converting bytes into characters using same encoding method. In your case, you would directly have byte stream and so can skip the step of encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty much the same, since the Crypto-APIs deal anyway always with byte streams or arrays.

This might help you: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/DotNetCrypto.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think you can read byte[] from file and just use simple encrypttion.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Don't use the crypto API.

Take a look into src + examples, at:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

Here's why:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSAKEY

Comment: You should qualify why that is a "Hint".