# AES Encryption in c#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I try to encrypt a file using the example MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx
When I encrypt a .txt file, then everything is fine, but when I try to encrypt other files (.bmp, .pdf ...), then the file is not decrypted.
Where is the error there?

I modified the code to download the file

```
internal static void EncryptAes(string pathData, string pathEnCrypt)
    {
        string plainText;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathData))
            plainText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        byte[] encrypted;
        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {

                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
            using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(pathEnCrypt, FileMode.Create))
                fstream.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "when I try to encrypt other files (.bmp, .pdf ...), then the file is not decrypted." Did you mean "then the file is not ENcrypted"? Or is it really the decryption afterwards that fails?

Comment: it is encrypted as it is strange, the size of the file is increased by half. And then it can decrypt, but to open it still will not work

Comment: Can you try just use BinaryReader and BinaryWriter instead (not StreamReader and StreamWriter) since bmp etc. are binary files...

Comment: The comment and code do not match: **decrytor** and **CreateEncryptor**. `// Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform. ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(((aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);`

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816121/encryption-and-decryption-binary-files-with-c-sharp

Comment: I changed to binary stream and an array of string. Now, all turns out. But when you restore the file is unknown to me its size before encryption. Therefore, the file is obtained, the size is the same as the encrypted, but in the end it is filled with zeros. Just so cut off from the file can not be zero (many types of files at the end of myself filled with zeros), I see the only way to pass in the size of the original file inside an encrypted, or to put a label on which then cut it off. But maybe someone knows an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

[StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) is supposed to work with text data in particular encoding. Hence you can't use it for binary data.

If file is not huge, you can read file contents into [MemmoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) and use it latter for AES.

Answer (score 0):

Acting on hex/binary data as if it was a string, will result in loss in data and so you won't be able to recover it fully. To get an/more idea you may want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987186/aes-encrypt-string-in-vb-net/37413712#37413712), it explains what you would like to do for VB.NET